# Is memory allocated with malloc or calloc deallocated at the end of a function?

Tags: c, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

I pass a pointer of a given type to a function.
In the function I allocate the memory needed:

```
Pointer = (mytype * ) malloc (N* sizeof (mytype));
```

And it all goes well. After the function ends another one calls pointer.

But the previously filled pointer is now without memory.

Shouldn't pointer have kept its filled memory?

Or does the ending of a function deallocate the memory?

Sorry but I am unable to paste my code because I work on a non connected PC.

Comment: **NO** if it isn't handled, it's called a memory leak...

Comment: There is another mistake if the pointer content is gone. But without code, we won't know.

Comment: Standard disclaimer: [Don't cast the result of `malloc` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you're not returning the pointer to the caller. The argument inside the function is not the same as the value at the calling site, so changing it by assigning the return value from `malloc()` doesn't change the caller's value.

This:

```
Foo *foo;

AllocateAFoo(foo);
```

has no chance of changing the value of `foo` *after* the function returns, even if the argument is assigned to inside the function. This is why `malloc()` *returns* the new value.

You need to do that also:

```
mytype * Allocate(size_t num)
{
  return malloc(num * sizeof (mytype));
}
```

This means that there's no point in sending the uninitialized pointer from the caller to the function, so don't.

Also, [you shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Also, you need to be aware that `malloc()` is just a function like any other. How would *you* write a function that reacts when execution leaves other functions? The answer is of course "you can't", and thus `malloc()` can't either.

Answer (score 4):

No. Memory allocated by malloc is not deallocated at the end of a function.

Otherwise, that would be a disaster, because you would be unable to write a function that creates a data structure by allocating memory for it, filling it with data, and returning it to the caller.

Comment: That is exactly what I am thinking but by debugging my program it seems that it is... weird

Comment: @Wing, don't confuse the local handle (pointer) to the memory being cleaned when it goes out of scope, with the memory itself being reclaimed.

Comment: I edited your answer to make it more clear. Hopefully, I didn't change the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [alloca()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/alloca), but that's not supported on all architectures.